# How to remove/hide 'to time' in time field

Tags: datetime

I need to show only one time, no need of start and end time. Or I need to show only start time. Please anyone help me on this.

Comment: Are we using date/events ? Please explain

Comment: Yes. I need to show only start time. How can I remove the end time field.

Comment: It's a configuration in field settings.. Edit field and change settings..

Comment: Thanks Anil. But I didn't see any section to hide the end time field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change in the field setting

Go to your content type, Now when we add a field of **Date** type. Then it will show a section for start and end date mentioned in the image

[image]

For already added field, you can not edit it i think because there is already content with end date. You can hide it if neccessary

Hope it will help!